# How is Blind affected by Unshakable?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The tooltip for the [Unshakable](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Unshakable) buff says:

> Gains defiant when targeted by crowd control skills. Blind is 10% effective. Weakness and vulnerability last 50% less time.

What does "Blind is 10% effective" mean? Are skills that normally cause blind only 10% as likely to inflict the condition? Or do they inflict the condition normally, but the enemy with Unshakable only has a 10% chance to miss? If that's the case, is the blind condition still cleared even if they don't miss an attack?

As a Thief who enjoys using the pistol offhand, I feel like I should probably know how Blind works on Champion-type enemies. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter.

Blind normally reduces the chance of hitting by 100%.

When an enemy with the "Unshakable" buff is hit with the Blind condition, it reduces their chance of hitting by only 10%.

As far as I'm aware, the Blind condition will be cleared, even if they end up hitting.

Comment: Considering that Blind is like "The next outgoing attack has X% chances to miss", the condition will fade even if the attack hits, because it was still the next outgoing attack... :)